# How to fix colorthief not changing bg-color

Tags: javascript, html, css, color-thief

So I'm making a profile picture uploader because I'm bored. I want it to be like when a user upload a image it extract color from the image using colorthief and change the `background-color` to the color it extracted but all I got is a error and it only works certain time.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/itzasyran/sw4ftp5u/

Snippet:

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
const imageDisplay = document.getElementById("imageDisplay");
const imageDisplayBlur = document.getElementById("imageDisplayBlur");
const dragContainer = document.querySelector(".drag-container");

const colorThief = new ColorThief();

fileInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  displayImage(file);
});

dragContainer.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dragContainer.classList.add("drag-over");
});

dragContainer.addEventListener("dragleave", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dragContainer.classList.remove("drag-over");
});

dragContainer.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dragContainer.classList.remove("drag-over");
  const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  displayImage(file);
});

const displayImage = (file) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    imageDisplay.src = reader.result;
    imageDisplayBlur.src = reader.result;

    const color = colorThief.getColor(imageDisplay);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${color[0]}, ${color[1]}, ${color[2]})`;
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Outfit&display=swap');
 :root {
  --bg-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  --primary-color: #fff;
  --font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  --logo-font: 'Outfit';
  --blur-animation-duration: 5s;
  --blur-animation-blur-start: 5px;
  --blur-animation-blur-mid: 10px;
  --blur-animation-blur-end: 5px;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}

form {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.title,
.drag {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
}

.disclaimer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-weight: 400;
}

.done {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(214, 214, 214, 0.8);
  padding: 10px;
}

.done h2 {
  color: #1f1f1f;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.done h2.donetxt {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 20vh;
}

#imageDisplay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 105%;
  max-height: 105%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: blur(5px);
  }

#imageDisplayBlur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>axysLib</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-thief/2.3.0/color-thief.umd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1 class="title">check log for da error</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    </form>
    <p class="drag">it mostly work here but not in VSCode or just normal in general</p>
    <div class="drag-container">
      <span class="drop-area" id="dropArea"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container">
    <img id="imageDisplay" src="#" aria-hidden="true">
    <img id="imageDisplayBlur" src="#" aria-hidden="true">
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4 class="disclaimer">{disclaimer}
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="done">
    <h2 class="donetxt">Upload</h2>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I rewrote the entire code and still doesn't work. It's supposed to change the bg-color instantly but mostly it doesn't change and took couple time for it to work. When I choose image it mostly stay in the dark bg-color or the previous color